# Change Comparator in MinMaxPriorityQueue guava

Tags: java, guava, priority-queue, comparator

I'm recently working with `MinMaxPriorityQueue`. My goal is to get the top Elements from some text files. The queue is working with `Ordering.natural()` but, I want to change it into `Ordering.natural().reverse()`. It didn't work, I don't know how to set it.

```
Comparator<Long> comp = Ordering.natural().reverse();
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Long> pq = MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(11).create();
pq.orderedBy(comp);
System.out.println(pq.comparator());
```

The output returns `Ordering.natural()` anyway. How can I manage this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you work with Guava ? You should add the library to the question

Comment: import com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue;
import com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue.Builder;

is this usefull?

Comment: Um, no code in the comments section, please. And "add the library to the question" means "edit the tags and add the Guava tag if that's the library you are using".

Comment: sorry, I'm new here :/ already get solved it, thanks anyway ! :)

Comment: Note, by the way, that if you're only actually using one end of the queue, what you have will perform significantly worse than a manually bounded `PriorityQueue`, or, much better, `Ordering.greatestOf`/`Ordering.leastOf`.  (`MinMaxPriorityQueue` is probably the most-misused API in Guava.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pass the `Comparator` at the creation time of queue otherwise it takes `Ordering.natural()` as default ordering. As per the javadocs

> If no comparator is given at construction time, the natural order of elements is used.

So if you need reverse ordering, create you queue with passing the `Comparator`

```
Comparator<Long> comp = Ordering.natural().reverse();
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Long> pq = MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(comp).maximumSize(11).create();
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of Guava's MinMaxPriorityQueue state:

> ... the queue's specified comparator. If no comparator is given at construction time, the natural order of elements is used.

It should be

```
Comparator<Long> comp = Ordering.natural().reverse();
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Long> pq = MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(comp)
        .maximumSize(11).create();
```

As you can see [in the docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html#orderedBy%28java.util.Comparator%29) `MinMaxPriorityQueue#orderedBy` is a static method and returns a `Builder`. You should only call that method via the class and it should tell you that the method *doesn't manipulate an instance*.

Guava works with the Builder pattern: Rather than offering methods to change the behaviour of an instance, it offers the possibility to set that behaviour before instantiating it (through a Builder). You set your attributes on the Builder and call `Builder#create` to get the instance.

For more information see [this question](/q/328496) and [this one](/q/15461083) or read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).